# Remodeling an old mechanic's garage into a conference space

Tags: insulation, painting

I am currently remodeling an old garage (Lube Center) into a conference space.

Right or wrong, this is what I'm doing.

I have already installed insulation with paper backing on the ceiling (Open Rafters) paper facing down. We ran furring strips along every 24 inches to support it, then our plan was to paint it black for the industrial look. The ceiling is about 18 feet high and I have no desire or ability to drywall the ceiling. Again, our plan was to just paint it.

AFTER I was done hanging it all, I noticed that the insulation said it had to be covered by something fire resistant. Someone said they've heard of a mesh material that would meet code, in fact our inspector said that would work, but no one knows where to get it. I know it's more expensive than drywall, but i need to find something I can put over it that is PAINTABLE.

Answer (score 4):

Many red flags. For one, that's not the right way to insulate a ceiling: if you want to use batts, you need to put rigid foam above the roof decking or leave ventilation channels between the roof decking and the insulation. For more info see http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/blogs/dept/musings/how-build-insulated-cathedral-ceiling

Furthermore, the fire code is nothing you want to be trying to skirt or do the bare minimum with. Fires are serious business. Do it right. An alternative to drywall is something called intumescent paint but I'm not sure that would work well in this application because the paper facers of the batts are too flexible and brittle to ensure continuous coverage for the life of the building.

It sounds like you need professional help, especially if you are planning to turn this into a commercial/institutional space. There are liability issues associated with potentially unsafe DIY work in buildings that will serve the public. Spend more money up front and have a better, safer, more nicely-finished building.